# String to function

Tags: mysql, bash, function, shell

I have the following Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function MySQLQuery()
{
        echo $1
        #mysql -u root -p << EOF
        #$1
        #EOF
}
MySQLQuery "SELECT * FROM kunden;"
```

But the Output is: SELECT install.sh FROM kunden.
It replaces the * to the name of the script.
How can I prevent this?

Or are there any better solutions?

Regards,
Vince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides what @Ansgar suggested,( `MySQLQuery 'SELECT * FROM kunden;'`),   you also need to enclose the `$1` parameter in quotes like :

`echo "$1"`.

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). Put the string in single quotes:

```
MySQLQuery 'SELECT * FROM kunden;'
```

and double-quote the parameter inside the function.

Comment: I tried that too. But the Output is still the same: SELECT install.sh FROM kunden;

Comment: The `*` will be expanded inside the function if the parameter is not quoted there, too.